# diffChangelog creates redundant changesets

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, liquibase

In my project we have a base entity, which other entities extend from

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue
  @Id
  UUID id;

  @Version private long version;

  @CreationTimestamp
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
  private LocalDateTime created;

  @UpdateTimestamp
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = true, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
  private LocalDateTime updated;
}
```

every time `diffChangelog` is run it creates new changesets `addDefaultValue` even though these were already set at table creation

```
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    id: 1660844241773-1
    author: bob (generated)
    changes:
    - addDefaultValue:
        columnDataType: timestamp WITH TIME ZONE
        columnName: created
        defaultValueComputed: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        tableName: foo
- changeSet:
    id: 1660844241773-2
    author: bob (generated)
    changes:
    - addDefaultValue:
        columnDataType: timestamp WITH TIME ZONE
        columnName: created
        defaultValueComputed: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        tableName: baz
- changeSet:
    id: 1660844241773-3
    author: bob (generated)
    changes:
    - addDefaultValue:
        columnDataType: timestamp WITH TIME ZONE
        columnName: created
        defaultValueComputed: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        tableName: bar
```

**liquibase.properties**

```
liquibase.hub.mode=off
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foo
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
changelogFile=src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.yml
referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.foo\
  ?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect\
  &hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy\
  &hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

Using liquibase-gradle-plugin v. 2.1.1

Liquibase versions

```
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.14.0'
    implementation 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:4.14.0'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.14.0'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.6'
    liquibaseRuntime 'info.picocli:picocli:4.6.3'
    runtimeClasspath 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.30'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:4.14.0'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.2'
```

Why are these changeset created, and is there any way to avoid them being generated?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a bug in the hibernate implementation. You can tell what liquibase is seeing as differences by running a `diff` operation. The diff command will tell you what is different, whereas diffChangeLog will take those differences and try to figure out how to resolve them.

It could be an issue with it incorrectly seeing differences, or it could be an issue with not correctly resolving the seen differences.

You'd be best off creating an issue at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues including what `diff` is reporting as the differences for you.